# Change Panel Language on Ricoh Aficio MP 301

Tags: printer, language

So we have a couple of Ricoh 301 MP printers.

I want to change the display panel on the printer to English.

Can't seem to get this done.

I've use the web interface and set the web interface to only English (deleted all other languages) - although English was already the first one, and it was still showing Spanish.

[image: Web Panel]

I've also navigated the front panel itself and can see that the setting has been lodged - but the display is still in Spanish, even after a reboot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how Ricoh tell you to do it, as per [this support page](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi_view/0001033/0001033318/view/usertool/unv/0006.htm). Admittedly the printer models shown on the page don't include yours, but try it anyway.

Press the [User Tools/Counter] key.
Select the menu.
To change the System Settings, press [System Settings].
To change the language used on the display, press [English].
Press Exit

[This page](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi_view/0001033/0001033318/view/usertool/unv/0221.htm) shows the display when changing language.

Answer (score 0):

@hdhondt's answer gave me the push I needed, but I'm going to answer the question as the steps on the Ricoh site are not 100% correct.

I've worked with computers for 40 years, and can't believe how long I spent pressing buttons on that thing to no avail.

Anyway here it is....

1) Press the User Tools/Counter Key

2) Press System Settings/ (Ajustes de sistema)

3) Press Down Arrow to show menu 2/2

4) Press English

[image]

[image]